DateTime.ToString with Format does not work in AutoMapper
My handler get all Appointments:
public async Task<Result<PagedResult<Responses.AppointmentResponse>>> Handle(Query.GetAppointmentQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var EventsQuery = GetAppointmentsQuery(request);

    var Events = await PagedResult<Domain.Entities.Appointment>.CreateAsync(EventsQuery,
            request.PageIndex, request.PageSize);

    var result = mapper.Map<PagedResult<Responses.AppointmentResponse>>(Events);

    return Result.Success(result);
}

Here is my AutoMapper profile:
CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentResponse>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UpdatedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<PagedResult<Appointment>, PagedResult<AppointmentResponse>>().ReverseMap();

My PagedResult pattern used in AutoMapper:
public PagedResult(List<T> items, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
{
    this.Items = items;
    this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    this.PageSize = pageSize;
    this.TotalCount = totalCount;
}

But my API output is:
"createdDate": "11/3/2024 1:25:25 PM",

result is MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PM like dateformat in my PC

Try manual mapping for this one and de if the problem is still there. If so, it's not the mapping but the serialization. I'd also recommend to unit test mappings.

If this is a JSON API, I'd suggest using a DateTime (or a nullable one) object in your AppointmentResponse object and then use appropriate attributes / converters to instruct the format used for serializing the value. If not, my advice is probably useless.

Can you tell us which kind of type your properties CreatedDate and UpdatedDate are in your AppointmentResponse class?

Oh I know my issue, my member use record for AppointmentResponse so it can't map

Good, you found something. Unfortunately nobody can follow you, because you didn't provide a minimal, reproducible example, which we could test on ourself.

@Panda what are you trying to do in the first place? Both formats are simply wrong. The standard way to represent dates in JSON, specified in RFC-7493, is ISO8601. Both System.Text.Json and Json.NET follow this already. This isn't a matter of opinion.  AutoMapper itself is NOT meant for formatting, it's meant for directly mapping objects by name,

Why aren't you using the standard format, which is understood and expected by all clients, browsers, JS libraries? Whatever receives these ambiguous strings will have to explicitly parse them with that explicit format, or risk producing incorrect dates


why don't you use the default serialization? 2) What's the actual field type and actual desired format? Is this a DateOnly? DateTime? DateTimeOffset? Do you only want the time part? 4) Why not use a custom converter? AutoMapper is simply not built to act as a serializer


That's not what AutoMapper is for, that's what JSON serializers are for. You can create a custom JSON formatter for eg DateTime and apply it either to all DateTime properties trhough JsonSerializerOptions,  or specific properties with the JsonConverter attribute.
But first THINK THREE times if you really want to do this. The standard way to specify dates in JSON is ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd) defined by RFC-7439. All clients expect this. input type='date' expects this, even if it displays localized values. Any client that receives the ambiguous "04/07/2024" value will have to not only explicitly parse it, but have to guess whether that's July 4th or April 7th.
JSON.NET, System.Text.Json and by extension ASP.NET Core already follow the standard.
If you insist, Write Custom Convertetrs in the docs show how to create a custom converter and even uses a DateTimeOffset converter as an example:
public class DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    public override DateTimeOffset Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString()!,
                "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(dateTimeValue.ToString(
                "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

You can change the type and format to whatever you want, eg DateOnly and European format:
public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
{
    public override DateOnly Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            DateOnly.ParseExact(reader.GetString()!,
                "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        DateOnly dateTimeValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(dateTimeValue.ToString(
                "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

As the docs show, you register apply that converter to specific properties using the Json
public class Customer
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public DateOnly CreatedDate{ get; set; }
    ...
}

Or through JsonSerializerOptions :
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Converters =
    {
        new DateOnlyJsonConverter()
    }
};

jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customer, serializeOptions);

In ASP.NET Core MVC and Web API you can regisgter the custom serializer with [AddJsonOptions()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.addjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0):
.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(options=>{
    options.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());    
});

In Minimal API you can register them either for the entire application
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
});

Or for specific endpoints/responses:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());


app.MapGet("/", () => 
    Results.Json(new Customer{ .. }, options));


Configure JSON Serializer Settings
You can configure the JSON serializer globally in your application to ensure that all dates follow the desired format.
If you're using ASP.NET Core, update the Startup.cs or Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    });

Create a custom DateTimeConverter:
csharp
public class DateTimeConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}


I did as you said but it didn't solve my problem. Adding more about my code, when I map 1 object it still work but when I map PagedResult it doesn't work.

I edited my comment, check it out again must be working
